# Python3 IndentationError: expected an indented block - should not throw this

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, indentation

All of a sudden, after coding with no problems on Textmate and Sublime, all of a sudden I get these error at random, IndentationError: expected an indented block.

I know thats a pretty newbie mistake.  I have not changed any settings on my text editors, the tabs are set for 4 spaces, I use PEP8.  Here is the code:

```
menu_choice = True

while menu_choice != 'E' or menu_choice != 'e':
    menu_choice = input('Enter your choice >>>')

    if menu_choice == 'A' or menu_choice == 'a':

        newcar = add_car()
        car_list.append(newcar)
        print(newcar)

    elif menu_choice == 'B' or menu_choice == 'b':

        stats = car_stats(car_list)
        print(stats)

    elif menu_choice == 'C' or menu_choice == 'c':

        print('\n\nDistance    Car Speed   Ideal Speed  Engine speed\n')
        for car in car_list:
            for t in range(11):
                arg = newcar.travel_time(t), newcar.speed(t), newcar.ideal_speed(t), newcar.engine_speed(t)
                s = map(lambda x: '{:0.2f}'.format(x), arg)
                s = map(lambda x: '{:<12s}'.format(x),s)
                print(' '.join(s))

    elif menu_choice == 'D' or menu_choice == 'd':
        for car in car_list:
            for t in range(11):

    elif menu_choice == 'E' or menu_choice == 'e':
        break
    else:
        print('Bad input! Try again!')
```

It does not like this line:

```
File "race.py", line 139
elif menu_choice == 'E' or menu_choice == 'e':
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

The weird thing is that it worked fine before and now that I come back to it decides to screw up right before it is due.  HELP PLAZE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line before:

```
for t in range(11):
```

It needs an indented block after it (hence the error). Write `pass` if you actually mean to do nothing:

```
for t in range(11):
    pass
```

Comment: @CB:  The block is already indented.  I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: actually i think you are right, that is not supposed to be there, I must have C/P incorrectly.